# xslt duplicate element and sort

Tags: xslt, sorting, copy, element

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [xslt copy then modify element and sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761186/xslt-copy-then-modify-element-and-sort)

I have some xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fruit namespace="basket">  
  <apple>
    <type>cox</type>
    <size>medium</size>
  </apple>  
  <orange>  
    <type>valencia</type>
    <size>large</size>
  </orange>  
</fruit>
```

Imagine there are more fruit instances and order can be anything.  I want to using an xslt:

1. Duplicate the apple elements and change the type element to "cooking apple".
2. Add that element in the results tree for the next bit
3. Sort all fruits, including the new added apple elements,  by type

I need it to look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fruit namespace="basket">  
  <apple>
    <type>cooking</type>
    <size>large</size>
  </apple>  
  <apple>
    <type>cox</type>
    <size>medium</size>
  </apple>  
  <orange>  
    <type>valencia</type>
    <size>large</size>
  </orange>  
</fruit>
```

Can anyone please show me how an xslt would like for this?

Comment: Is this homework? The data doesn't seem especially commercial!

Answer (score 0):

If you have XSLT 2.0 or are allowed to use EXSLT then [`exslt:node-set`](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html) is the way to go.

Declare a variable containing the node to be added, like this

```
<xsl:variable name="fruit">
  <apple>
    <type>cooking</type>
    <size>large</size>
  </apple>
</xsl:variable>
```

and use it with `exslt:node-set()` together with the existing nodes in a sorted `<xsl:for-each>`, like this

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    <xsl:for-each select="*|exslt:node-set($fruit)">
      <xsl:sort select="type" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="current()" />        
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

If you are using XSLT 2.0 then you can remove the `exslt:node-set()` call from around the variable. Otherwise remember to use `exclude-result-prefixes="exslt"` to keep the output tidy!

Comment: Thanks for your input. It's appreciated. I can only use xslt 1.0...  is something similar possible in that version

Comment: Does your XSLT processor have the EXSLT extensions?

Comment: No. I'm finding it difficult to copy the a type of element and then sort the list with the new element.